# Zxing Barcode 128 Recognition problems

Tags: java, zxing, barcode-scanner, code128

I'm using zxing as a barcode-scanner to scan code128 barcodes. The problem I face is that I can only scan really big generated images (i.e. 1680 * 529 pixels) like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZuLx.jpg). If I'm trying to scan [an image taken by me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mfmm.jpg) which is a little bit larger (2181 * 781 pixels) neither my program nor the [zxing online scanner](https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx) works. The image format is png and I need to be able to scan normal images of the whole package I take pictures of, instead of the ones with only the barcode zoomed-in visible. Because of sizerestriction of stackoverflow I converted both pictures to jpg so their size isn't over 2MB anymore.

PS: in my program I've enabled the TRY_HARDER mode all the time.